It's farther away than I'd thought

(1) It's farther away than I'd thought. (source)
(2) It's farther away than I thought. (my sentence)
(3) It was farther away than I'd thought. (my sentence)

Could someone please explain why the past perfect d thought (= had thought) works in (1)? I would expect (2) or (3).
(I don't know whether the past perfect is mandatory in (3).)

Consider this simple sentence:

It tastes good.

If you are eating something and you say "It tastes good" you are referring to what you tasted just a moment ago and you are offering your opinion of it. But you can also say "It tastes good" when someone has asked you about something that they have never eaten before and you are familiar with it, having eaten it many times. In that case you are offering a general opinion about it which is based on your past experiences with it. You have eaten it many times.
But there was a time when you had never eaten it before. You had not tried it yet. You can remember the first time you ate it. You can also remember looking at it and thinking to yourself "It doesn't look very good. I wonder why people eat it?" But then you took a taste of it, and you liked it.
You can tell someone now about your first time eating it years ago:

It tasted better than I had expected.

But if someone was with you on that first occasion, you could have turned to them and said:

It tastes better than I had expected.

or

It tastes better than I expected.

The past perfect  presents your expectation as existing before you tasted it and as something that ended when you tasted it; the simple past presents your expectation as existing in the past.
The past perfect is explicit about the sequence of events and the result of the tasting experience. The simple past allows the obvious to speak for itself. The sequence of events is so simple and intuitive that the past perfect is unnecessary there.

The sense of (1) is "I used to think that 'it' was quite near, but when I saw (it in reality/an accurate map/whatever) I realised that it was farther away that I had previously thought".
As has often been said on this forum, you can use the simplest tense that conveys the intended meaning. So people might well use your sentence (2) without any risk of confusion.

Indeed. The OP doesn't provide the 4th permutation (Simple Past throughout), but I find It was more than I expected perfectly okay. I can't compare usage figures with It was more than I had expected, because NGrams limits us to 5 words. In any case, NGrams is all written text, so more likely to be fussy about verb forms. But I'd certainly endorse  the simplest version for spoken contexts, when there's no possibility of meaningful ambiguity.
